# Server Swift with mongodb manager singleton

Tags: swift, mongodb, vapor

I am working on a project using `Vapor` and `Mongodb`. 
Let's say that at a specific route

```
    drop.get("user", String.self) { request, user in
       // ... query Mongodb
    }
```

I want to query the database and see if an input user already exists. 
Is it wise to have a singleton `MongoManager` class that handles all the connection with the database?

```
drop.get("user", String.self) { request, user in
           MongoManager.sharedInstance.findUser(user)
        }
```

Do I create a bottleneck with this implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not create a bottleneck unless you have a single-threaded mechanism that stands between your Vapor Handler and MongoDB.

MongoKitten (the underlying driver for Swift + MongoDB projects) manages the connection pool internally. You can blindly fire queries at MongoKitten and it'll figure out what connection to use or will create a new one if necessary.

Users of MongoKitten 3 will use a single connection per request. If multiple requests are being handled simultaneously, additional connections will be opened.

Users of MongoKitten 4 will use a single connection for 3 requests, this is configurable. The connection pool will expand by opening more connections if there are too many requests are being done.

Users of the upcoming Meow ORM (which works similar to what you're building) will use a single connection per thread. The connection pool will expand if all connections are reserved.